# Sphinxql with PDO php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, sphinxql

I am integrating Sphinxsearch into my site, and rewriting my old code to use Sphinx.
The problem i got is with special characters inside MATCH in SphinxQL.
Example : want to search for H&M
With plain mysql i get thousand of records, so im quite sure i got title's containing that word in my database.
I don't need extended query syntax in MATCH.

```
$q = "h&m";  
$spxq = "SELECT * FROM sphinx_index WHERE MATCH(:query) LIMIT 0,10";  
$stmt = $DB->prepare($spxq);  
$stmt->bindValue(':query', $q, PDO::PARAM_STR);  
$stmt->execute();  
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

This isn't returning any results.
After this i tried escaping $q so :

```
$q = "h\&m";
```

Still not working.Tried with double escaping too, still not working.
Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i got this, if anyone in the future has this same problem.
The solution is to add the special characters you want to be able to search for in the **sphinx.conf** file, in the **charset_table**.

So for my case of H&M, you need to add the & character (U+026) in to the charset table.